# Cant Import cordapp-example into IntelliJ 181.4892.42

Tags: corda

Steps

1. cd \users\user1
2. git clone https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example
3. cd cordapp-example
4. start IntelliJ
5. click "open"
6. On "Open Fie or Project" selecte folder \users\user1\cordapp-example
7. Click "OK"

At this point IntelliJ does not show the "Unlinked Grade Project?" pop-up. And the nothing in small baloon (Assume the event log, that is grey).

Closing and reopening IntelliJ also does not help.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you open a CorDapp project has changed in IntelliJ 2018. Please see the updated instructions on the `master` branch of the Corda docs: https://docs.corda.net/head/getting-set-up.html#run-from-intellij.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

I got close, but selected "Create Module from existing sources" and that did not work ;-)

I think I found some mistakes on the latest instruction, but I'll start another post for consistency.

Comment: Thanks, please do :)